# How to extract and display only the current temperature in weatherzone?

Tags: c#, xml, weather-api

Fetching the data from weatherzone by C# code :

```
string url = "http://rss.weatherzone.com.au/?u=12994-1285&lt=twcid&lc=160255&obs=1&fc=1";
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(url);
SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
reader.Close();
```

Get current weather :

```
var temperature = feed.Items.ToList()[0].Summary.Text.Trim();
```

Output :

```
<b>Temperature:</b> 33.0&#176;C
<img align="top" src="http://www.weatherzone.com.au/images/widgets/nav_trend_steady.gif" alt="steady"/>
<br />
<b>Feels like:</b> 38.0&#176;C<br />
<b>Dew point:</b> 23.0&#176;C
<img align="top" src="http://www.weatherzone.com.au/images/widgets/nav_trend_steady.gif" alt="steady"/>
<br />
<b>Relative humidity:</b> 56%<br />
<b>Wind:</b> NE at 18 km/h, gusting to  km/h
<img align="top" src="http://www.weatherzone.com.au/images/widgets/nav_trend_steady.gif" alt="steady"/>
<br />
<b>Rain:</b> mm since 9am<br />
<b>Pressure:</b> 1013.0 hPa
<img align="top" src="http://www.weatherzone.com.au/images/widgets/nav_trend_steady.gif" alt="steady"/>
<br />
```

Question : How I can get Temperature in this output ?

Comment: What is your `SyndicationFeed`? Can you provide the full namespace, please?

Comment: hi, you can add using System.ServiceModel.Syndication from System.ServiceModel.dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something crude like this:

```
var stringTemp = "<b>Temperature:</b> 33.0&#176;C <img align=\"top\" src=\"http://www.weatherzone.com.au/images/widgets/nav_trend_steady.gif\" alt=\"steady\"/> <br /> <b>Feels like:</b> 38.0&#176;C<br /> <b>Dew point:</b> 23.0&#176;C <img align=\"top\" src=\"http://www.weatherzone.com.au/images/widgets/nav_trend_steady.gif\" alt=\"steady\"/> <br /> <b>Relative humidity:</b> 56%<br /> <b>Wind:</b> NE at 18 km/h, gusting to km/h <img align=\"top\" src=\"http://www.weatherzone.com.au/images/widgets/nav_trend_steady.gif\" alt=\"steady\"/> <br /> <b>Rain:</b> mm since 9am<br /> <b>Pressure:</b> 1013.0 hPa <img align=\"top\" src=\"http://www.weatherzone.com.au/images/widgets/nav_trend_steady.gif\" alt=\"steady\"/> <br />";
var start = stringTemp.IndexOf("</b>");
var end = stringTemp.IndexOf("<img");
var temp = stringTemp.Substring(start + "</b>".Length, end - start - "<img".Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
var temperature = "<b>Temperature:</b> 33.0&#176;C <img align=\"top\" src=\"http://www.weatherzone.com.au/images/widgets/nav_trend_steady.gif\" alt=\"steady\"/> <br /> <b>Feels like:</b> 38.0&#176;C<br /> <b>Dew point:</b> 23.0&#176;C <img align=\"top\" src=\"http://www.weatherzone.com.au/images/widgets/nav_trend_steady.gif\" alt=\"steady\"/> <br /> <b>Relative humidity:</b> 56%<br /> <b>Wind:</b> NE at 18 km/h, gusting to km/h <img align=\"top\" src=\"http://www.weatherzone.com.au/images/widgets/nav_trend_steady.gif\" alt=\"steady\"/> <br /> <b>Rain:</b> mm since 9am<br /> <b>Pressure:</b> 1013.0 hPa <img align=\"top\" src=\"http://www.weatherzone.com.au/images/widgets/nav_trend_steady.gif\" alt=\"steady\"/> <br />";
```

C# :

```
    private static string Temperature(string temperature)
    {
        try
        {
            string[] value = Regex.Split(temperature, "\n");
            string[] temp = Regex.Split(value[0], "</b> ");
            return temp[1].Substring(0, 2);
        }
        catch { return string.Empty; }
    }
```